# Is it necessary to add status_code and msg in response of Rest Framework APIs? If so, how?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to add `status_code` and `msg` to a rest framework api?

A sample response by the django's rest framework API will be as shown in below snapshot:

[image: Snapshot showing sample API response]

In the Java APIs, we usually return API response in the below format:

```
{
    "status_code":200,
    "msg":"success",
    "data":[the_data] # the_data is  API response as shown in snapshot
}
```

`the_data` is the data list like upper snapshot data.

So the question is,
Is it necessary to add `status_code` and `msg` in the Djano's Rest Framework API response? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to add status_code in DRF api because it's already included in the Response class. Check this for detail: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response. And the api above is called browsable API which generating human-friendly HTML output, status_code and msg you want is already there(HTTP 200 OK), 200 is the status_code, ok is the msg. Hope this answer your question.